Optimal decision for asymmetric loss function
Let $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and consider the loss function
$$\ell(y, a) := (y-a)^2(c_1\mathbb{1}_{a \leq y}(y) + c_2\mathbb{1}_{y < a})$$
where $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}_+$. I've been trying to determine the optimal decison
$$a^* = \arg\min_{a \in \mathbb{R}} \mathbb{E}[\ell(Y,a) ] $$
but I've been unable to compute it. My attempt:
$$\arg\min_{a} \mathbb{E}[\ell(Y,a) ] = \arg\min_{a} \mathbb{E}\big[(Y-a)^2(c_1\mathbb{1}_{a \leq Y}(Y) + c_2\mathbb{1}_{Y < a}(Y))\big] =$$
$$= \arg\min_{a} \mathbb{E}\big[(Y-a)^2(c_1(1-\mathbb{1}_{Y < a}(Y)) + c_2\mathbb{1}_{Y < a}(Y))\big] =$$ $$=\arg\min_{a} \mathbb{E}\big[(Y-a)^2(c_1 + (c_2 - c_1) \mathbb{1}_{Y < a}(Y)\big] =$$
$$=\arg\min_a \Big(c_1\mathbb{E}\big[(Y-a)^2\big] + (c_2-c_1)\mathbb{E}\big[(Y-a)^2\mathbb{1}_{Y<a}\big]\Big)$$
$$ = \arg\min_a \bigg(c_1\mathbb{E}\big[(Y-a)^2\big] + (c_2-c_1) \int_{-\infty}^a(y-a)^2p_Y(y)dy\bigg),$$
where $p_Y(y)$ is the pdf of $Y$. However, at this point I don't know to make any progress. Is there anyway that this optimal decision can be analitically computed? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Optimal for what? If you take the derivative with respect to a and set it to zero what is your result? Why shouldn't the result just be something where the errors enter asymmetrically?

@Ggjj11 I don't see how taking the derivative with respect to $a$ would help here, since $a$ is the upper bound of the integral. When I compute the derivative with respect to $a$, I get $$\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \mathbb{E}[\ell(Y,a)] = 2c_1a - 2c_1\mu -(c_2-c_1) \bigg( -2 \int_{-\infty}^a y p_Y(y)dy + 2a\mathbb{P}(Y \leq a)\bigg)$$, and I don't see how I could set this to zero and solve for $a$.

You might find it helpful (and insightful) to resort to the basic definition of the derivative as a limiting value of the difference quotient.  Often, sketching a graph in which $a$ is varied a little will reveal (geometrically and visually) what that difference is and make it evident where it equals zero.

Note that$$\int_{-\infty}^a (y-a) p_Y(y)\text dy = \int_{-\infty}^a F_Y(y)\text dy$$which may help when the integral has a closed form solution.

@Dude3400 Suppose your derivative in the second comment is correct, you can solve it for $a$ with numerical methods. I don't think closed form solution exists.

@NN2 That's correct, because the equation is transcendental: it involves a linear combination of an algebraic function of $a,$ $\phi,$ and $\Phi$ (the normal pdf and cdf). But I would expect one or two Newton-Raphson iterations around any reasonable starting point would suffice in any case.

Also implementing this in pytorch and using some of the sgd-based solvers there will converge for minimizing your loss - pretty sure! Let us know what properties you find for the solution ...

The asymmetric squared loss you give is minimized in expectation by the $\tau$-expectile of $Y$ (given $Y$ has finite first moment) for $\tau = 1/ (c_1 + c_2)$. In general, the expectile of a distribution cannot be computed analytically. However, we can show that it is the unique minimizer of this loss.
References

Newey and Powell (1987). Asymmetric Least Squares Estimation and Testing, Econometrica
(https://doi.org/10.2307/1911031)
Gneinting (2011). Making and Evaluating Point Forecasts, Journal of the American Statistical Association (https://doi.org/10.1198/jasa.2011.r10138)

